# Java, activemq, Change settings of the message listener during the subscription

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Is there a way to pass some variables other than the activemq message into the onMessage method during the subscription? Say if I have a gui which starts and stops this client and I want to change something in the message listener if I click a button in the gui. Is there anything I could do to achieve this?

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
   // how to swith between setting 1 and setting 2??    
   //setting 1
   //save message to file         
   //setting 2      
            System.out.println("Received message" + textMessage.getText()
                    + "'");

        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

Comment: Thanks, but the example is actually not describing what I want to do....The exact story is, I have a gui, and I want to change some settings in the message listener when I click a button. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> The exact story is, I have a gui, and I want to change some settings
>   in the message listener when I click a button.

You need to pass that setting via some singleton/db/etc to the message handler.

In case if the message listener needs to write to a console you resend the message to the same queue/topic with the delayed property set as here https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. However I am not very familiar with what you are suggesting. Is there any chance that you could post a simple example here please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm.. You mean how to send a message or how to set a property to the message? or how to pass settings the message listener? To answer any of these I need to know the architecture of the application at least (what runs where) and what libs you are using. And even then, answering to any of these questions would be a separate question in terms of SO :)